# Equation in footnote causes empty footnote on next page

Tags: equations, line-breaking, footnotes

I have a footnote in a standard `article` document that happens to be at the bottom of a page, and the footnote ends with an `equation` environment. This causes the footnote to continue on the next page (I guess this is because some sort of white space is inserted after the `equation` environment), even though there's nothing left to be displayed. How can the empty footnote on the next page be avoided?

See bottom of p. 2 in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext[4]

Here comes a footnote ending on an equation.\footnote{That's the equation:
\begin{equation}
    a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
}
And here continues the text. As you can see, on the bottom of p.2 there is line from the footnote although the whole footnote is printed on the first page. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a \vskip at the end of the equation which doesn't fit. You can see this by placing the entire footnote inside a \parbox[t][\dimexpr \linewidth-\bibindent}{...}.

Comment: How do I see this? In my case the footnote just disappears... There's a small typo btw, should be "{" instead of "[" before \dimexpr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can squeeze the footnote onto page 1 if you are willing to hang 4pt over the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext[4]

Here comes a footnote ending on an equation.\footnote{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][\dimexpr\depth-4pt]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\bibindent}%
{\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
That's the equation:
\begin{equation}
    a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}}}}
And here continues the text. As you can see, on the bottom of p.2 there is line from the footnote although the whole footnote is printed on the first page. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. Putting a box around the footnote content is a good idea. Then depending on the parameters it either squeezes the equation on the page or it would automatically push the entire footnote to the next page, which is still better than having an empty footnote standing alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the break point by setting a penalty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext[4]

Here comes a footnote ending on an equation.\footnote{That's the equation:
\postdisplaypenalty=10000
\begin{equation}
    a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
}
And here continues the text. As you can see, on the bottom of p.2 there is line from the footnote although the whole footnote is printed on the first page. \blindtext
\end{document}
```